# php split number and plus them

Tags: php, html, split

With PHP I need to add all the digits in a number.

Example : if I have 142 it will be 1+4+2 = 7

its should be 1 to 9 if not its should plus again 11 will be 1+1 = 2

Comment: did you try something or..?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function, based on Dave Chen's answer :

```
function sumDigits($input) {
    $sum = array_sum(str_split($input));
    if($sum > 9) {
        $sum = sumDigits($sum);
    }

    return $sum;
}
```

This code :

```
echo sumDigits("1239");
```

Outputs: `6`

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 9 = 15 = 1 + 5 = 6
```

Comment: My answer is wrong, congrats on getting the whole thing correct +1.

Comment: @DaveChen Your answer is not wrong. It is the path!

Comment: Thanks to you, You gave me the tricks !